# JUnit тестирование

Tags: java, тестирование, junit

Когда при JUnit тестировании целесообразно создавать методы `setUp` и `tearDown`?

Необходимо ли при тестировании методов следующего класса создавать эти методы(`setUp` и `tearDown`)? Или создавать каждый раз все объекты для создания объекта Универ, чтобы протестировать один метод?

```
public class University {
private List<Student> students;
private List<Group> groups;
private List<Teacher> teachers;
private List<Audience> audiences;
private List<Lecture> lectures;
private Schedule schedule;


public University(List<Student> students, List<Group> groups, List<Teacher> teachers, List<Audience> audiences,
        List<Lecture> lectures, Schedule schedule) {
    this.students = students;
    this.groups = groups;
    this.teachers = teachers;
    this.audiences = audiences;
    this.lectures = lectures;
    this.schedule = schedule;
}

public void enroll(Student student, Group group) {...}

public void expel(Student student) {...}

public void form(Group group) {...}

public void disband(Group group) {...}

public void changeGroup(Student student, Group group) {...}

public void hire(Teacher teacher) {...}

public void fire(Teacher teacher) {...}

public void appoint(Lecture lecture) {...}

public void cansel(Lecture lecture) {...}

public Schedule viewSchedule() {...}
```

Comment: зависит от вашей задачи

Comment: как было бы правильней? И какие нужны условия, чтобы определить вариант под мою задачу?

Comment: например, вы не хотите завязываться на какие то данные и каждый раз должны гененрировать рандомные данные для уичтелей и студентов. тогда каждый раз @before метод должен создавать эти данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда мы создаем тестовые методы с помощью JUnit, то мы обычно настраиваем наши собственные тестовые данные и объекты конфигурации, которые могут использоваться в наших тестах.

Нам нужно, чтобы наши тестовые данные были легко доступны. Когда мы выполняем каждый из тестовых сценариев, эти данные будут использоваться системой во время выполнения.

Мы можем подготовить наши тестовые данные в тестовых методах, но такое использование данных не будет целесообразно ввиду того, что эти данные могут дублироваться.

Тогда мы можем выносить создание тестовых данных в методы `setup` и `tearDown`. Эти методы будут вызываться для каждого вызова тестового метода. Это позволит тестовому сценарию выполнить подготовку данных и очистку после каждого вызова тестового метода.